# Why do bosonic atoms behave like they do?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, pauli-exclusion-principle

Why do bosonic particles behave the way they do? Why doesn't the Pauli exclusion principle affect the electrons, protons, and neutrons of the atoms at temperatures close to absolute zero? How does spin factor in?